# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in <input id={{ vendor.id }}

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, firebase

I'm trying to submit the form on click function on input[type='checkbox'] without refreshing the page using ajax-jquery. Btw I'm developing a Django web app.

Here is my Form element code-

```
{% if vendor.accountEnabled %}
    <form id="form" action="{% url 'change_account_switch' vendor.id %}"
                                              method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">     
             <input onclick="switchAcc('{{ vendor.id }}customSwitch1');"
                                                       type="checkbox"
                                                       name="switch"
                                                       class="custom-control-input" id="{{ vendor.id }}customSwitch1"
                                                       checked>
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ vendor.id }}customSwitch1">Enable</label>
        </div>
    </form>
{% else %}
    <form id="form" action="{% url 'change_account_switch' vendor.id %}"
                                              method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                <input onclick="switchAcc('{{ vendor.id }}customSwitch1');"
                                                       type="checkbox"
                                                       name="switch"
                                                       class="custom-control-input" id="{{ vendor.id }}customSwitch1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ vendor.id }}customSwitch1">Enable</label>
          </div>
      </form>
{% endif %}
```

Here is my JS code-

```
 function switchAcc(cb_id) {

            let switchBtn = $('#' + cb_id).is(':checked');

            console.log(switchBtn)
            console.log(cb_id)

            $.ajax({
                url: $('#form').attr('action'),
                data: {
                    'status': switchBtn
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    if (data.is_done) {
                        alert("A user with this username already exists.");
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });

        }
```

Django views.py ----

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def change_account_switch(request, doc_id):
    ref = db.collection('vendorUsers').document(doc_id)
    switch = request.GET.get('status', None)
    if switch == 'true':
        switch = True
    elif switch == 'false':
        switch = False
    ref.update({
        'accountEnabled': switch,
    })

    data = {
        'is_done': ref.get().to_dict()['accountEnabled'],
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I'm having one more problem. look at my form element code in there I'm showing multiple users and each user contains accountEnabled field in their profile database. . . .

Now, look at my views.py code. In that file I'm updating accountEnabled field on the basis of the switch button (checkbox). . . .

But the problem is, only the first user's accountEnabled field is updating in the list. –

Comment: Where's the `input` tag from the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass parameter in your function using `''` that's the reason of the error currently you get.Other error you have missed `,` near `}.error..` ,then you have calling your action of form in wrong way it should be `$('form').attr('action')` and this `{#url: '/ajax/change_account_switch/{{ doc_id }}',#}` was also giving error.

Working jquery code :

```js
function switchAcc(doc_id) {
  console.log("vendor_id ="+doc_id); //your id
  let switchBtn = $('input[name="switch"]').checked;
  console.log("form_action = "+$('form').attr('action'));
  $.ajax({
  // {#url: '/ajax/change_account_switch/{{ doc_id }}',#}
    url: $('form').attr('action'), //form action
    data: {
      'status': switchBtn
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      if (data.is_done) {
        alert("A user with this username already exists.");
      }
    }, //, was missing
    error: function(e) {
      //console.log(e.message);
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="{% url 'change_account_switch' vendor.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <!--use here '{{ vendor.id }}'-->
    <input onclick="switchAcc('{{ vendor.id }}');" type="checkbox" name="switch" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Enable</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm having one more problem. look at my form element code in there I'm showing multiple users and each user contains accountEnabled field in their profile database.
.
.
.
Now, look at my views.py code. In that file I'm updating accountEnabled field on the basis of the switch button (checkbox).
.
.
.
But the problem is, only the first user's accountEnabled field is updating in the list.

Comment: I have updated the above question according to your answer @Swati. Please take a look at the bottom of the question and try to answer.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about django , but to update particular checkbox you need to pass `cb_id` also to your backend page to update only those checkbox whose `cb_id` is checked .

Comment: Okay I'll try @Swati. Thanks